# About Python format

Tags: python

I have a question about the python format:

```
query_score = {query_id:set((doc_id, score)
                            for v, query in queries.items()
                            for document in txt_filenames
                                doc_id = document.split('\\')[-1]
                                score = cos(query, texts[doc_id])))
               for query_id, b in queries.items()}
```

It says it has an "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". It there any question about that two sentences below the for loop? 
I'm new to python so that any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Also, is this really how you have indented your code?

Comment: I look at this code and all I have to say is: [WAT?](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7032/files/wat_explained_grande.jpg?113131)

Comment: I'm going to get a set that contains each query's id in terms of each document and the score between them.

Comment: I think the question is the syntax. But not the content.

Comment: You can't assign within a list comprehension.

Comment: I think one of the key focus of Python is readability and this looks complex. You may want to break it down and then build on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define variables in the middle of a comprehension, so you will need to inline those lines after the for, e.g.:

```
query_score = {query_id: set((document.split('\\')[-1], cos(query, texts[doc_id]))
                             for v, query in queries.items()
                             for document in txt_filenames)
               for query_id, b in queries.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you may have an extra parenthesis at the end of the second to last line.  Getting rid of the extra may fix the problem.

Comment: yea, I make a mistake. But after I get rid of it. It still says I have a  "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" problem.